# Makefile not producing any output

Tags: makefile

It has been ages since I wrote a `Makefile`, so may be this is a very silly question. So please forgive me if I came here to ask, but I cannot understand the behaviour of `make` with the `Makefile` that follows. In all the executions below, the folder `output/` and the output files do not exist, so they should be built.

```
.PHONY: all

all: $(FILES2)

FLD ::= output/
FILES1 ::= $(addprefix $(FLD), out11 out12)
FILES2 ::= $(addprefix $(FLD), out21 out22)
$(warning FILES1: $(FILES1))
$(warning FILES2: $(FILES2))

$(FILES1): script1.py
    python3 script1.py --output_fld=$(FLD)

$(FILES2): $(FILES1) script2.py
    python3 script2.py --output_fld=$(FLD)
```

When run with `make -f Makefile`, I get:

```
Makefile:8: FILES1: output/out11 output/out12
Makefile:9: FILES2: output/out21 output/out22
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

When run with `make -d -f Makefile`, I get a long list of messages ending with:

```
Considering target file 'all'.
 File 'all' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'all'.
Must remake target 'all'.
Successfully remade target file 'all'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

When run with `make output/out11` (or `make output/out12`) (i.e. with an explicit target) I get:

```
make output/out11
Makefile:8: FILES1: output/out11 output/out12
Makefile:9: FILES2: output/out21 output/out22
python3 script1.py --output_fld=output/
```

I am using GNU Make V4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I have seen that Make v4.3 introduced a special syntax for grouped targets, but I cannot use it here.

Now, the question: what do I need to correct (and understand) in order to have `make all` actually executing the commands for building the targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
all: $(FILES2)
  ...
FILES2 ::= $(addprefix $(FLD), out21 out22)
```

When the `all` target is defined, the `FILES2` variable is not set yet, so it expands to the empty string, so `all` has no prerequisites and no recipe to build it, so there's nothing for make to do here.

Comment: (And the solution is to move the `all: ...` line below the `FILES2 ::= ...` line.)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$(FILES2)` does not contain any value and `all` target has no pre-requisites. In order to solve this issue, define the variables `FILES1`  and `FILES2` before as shown:

```
.PHONY: all
FLD ::= output/
FILES1 ::= $(addprefix $(FLD), out11 out12)
FILES2 ::= $(addprefix $(FLD), out21 out22)


$(warning FILES1: $(FILES1))
$(warning FILES2: $(FILES2))
all: $(FILES2)

$(FILES1): script1.py
    echo "Executing script 1"
    python3 script1.py --output_fld=$(FLD)

$(FILES2): $(FILES1) script2.py
    echo "Executing script 2"
    python3 script2.py --output_fld=$(FLD)
```